# Battery is not communicating?

Tags: canon, error, canon-70d

Main problem is that no battery percentage is showing on display?

How to solve this problem?

[image: no battery communication]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Canon EOS 5D Mark IV is asking if the inserted battery is original or not. What are the implications of my answer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87558/my-canon-eos-5d-mark-iv-is-asking-if-the-inserted-battery-is-original-or-not-wh)