# Can a cheap DX battery damage my camera?

Tags: canon, battery, third-party

I would like to purchase a spare battery for my new [Canon EOS 550D\Rebel T2i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_550D) for a trip abroad.

I've found [this battery on DealExtreme](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/canon-lp-e8-compatible-7-4v-1200mah-battery-pack-for-canon-550d-35588). It costs 6.90$ (with shippment), a small fraction from the street price.

What are the chances this battery will damage my camera?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I buy an original manufacturer battery, or is a generic brand OK?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/should-i-buy-an-original-manufacturer-battery-or-is-a-generic-brand-ok)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate. He just wants to know if this battery will do damage, not if all generic batteries are a good or bad idea for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The chances are high.** Nikon started putting holograms on their batteries so they would be recognized as originals because some fakes burst into flames after some use.

Most importantly, is why are you even considering this? You paid good money for a nice camera and you want to risk it by saving some money on a cheap battery? If the one you have is not enough, even one more will give you at least another 400-shots per charge unless you use the flash more than you should.

Comment: I think the _actual_ chances of damage to your camera are quite low. More likely it will just be lower capacity than advertised and not last for many cycles. Nikon's addition of the hologram has more to do with protecting their bottom line than protecting consumer interests. And this particular model is just a generic replacement; it isn't a "pirate" knock-off blatantly masquerading as the real thing. But that said, **I do agree with @Itai's conclusion** — the manufacturer-branded batteries aren't that much more expensive and you _do_ get something for your money.

Comment: The chances are HIGH that it will damage a camera? So as in over 50% of the time that you get a generic battery you think it will do damage?

Comment: Actually, to keep cost down manufacturers apparently use less internal shielding, causing more heat dissipation. From what I read, you are right they last fewer cycles though, although sometimes they have a higher maximum capacity. I'm guessing since they save room on shielding ;)

Comment: I've often heard of such batteries leak or oxidize the contacts. I read the original Nikon story about flaming batteries but no directly. It seems like the chances are high but maybe the media was exaggerating. I know of no official stats though.

Comment: If you wasn't US based I'd recommend 7dayshop. You could look on amazon though for Energizer batteries. They're a well known brand and make them for my 500D so I'm guessing they'll have 550D ones too. Whilst this is a good brand though, one of mine did start to crack and bulge which I sent back on warranty

Comment: Scrap that couldn't find them on amazon US, but they're Energizer CA-LPE8 if you want to google. Much much cheaper, and at least a proper brand rather than some scary random chinese one

Comment: @Itai - I have never seen a battery *with* shielding, and batteries do not need shielding. What are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry perhaps *shielding* is not the right term. I saw someone take apart a real and fake battery and he showed the difference but pointing at the layers between the cells and the outer plastic casing. The fake one was missing a layer.

Answer (score 4):

### Maybe, but **Probably Not**

Third party batteries vary in quality and capacity, but their actual danger is **massively** exaggerated.
Furthermore, the Chinese battery failures generally happen when the device is charging. Unless you have a camera which lets you charge your battery *in* the camera, even a spectacular failure will not likely damage the camera itself, and such an event is very rare.

Consider how many batteries you have heard of failing, versus the number of third party batteries that have ever been sold (Millions!). I would rate the risk as quite low.