# What is the trade-off with Energizer-brand compatible battery packs?

Tags: canon, battery, third-party

The difference in price between the [Canon LP-E4](http://www.warehouseexpress.com/buy-canon-lp-e4-battery-pack/p1018249) battery back and the [equivalent model](http://www.warehouseexpress.com/buy-energizer-ca-lpe4-lpe4-battery/p1524816) from Energizer is significant. What, if any, are the main disadvantages to purchasing the cheaper model as opposed to the Canon brand version?

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicate of [Should I buy an original manufacturer battery, or is a generic brand OK?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/should-i-buy-an-original-manufacturer-battery-or-is-a-generic-brand-ok), but third-party batteries from a well-recognized brand name like Energizer is different twist.

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't find any duplicate questions, and that one wasn't suggested. I have to admit I was surprised it hadn't been asked already.

Comment: @NickMiners: Could you link the one your referring to? There are usually differences in specification, such as amperes, whether they supply the necessary feedback data, etc. Generally speaking, the cheapest third-party compatible packs provide the bear minimum data feedback, and often don't provide on-spec power, and often don't supply as much power (less batter life).

Comment: There's a list of Energizer-branded compatible batteries [here](http://www.energizerbatteries.com/productList.asp?device=DIGCAM), but they don't seem to list a LP-E4 replacement.

Comment: Whilst my energizer batteries have worked just as well, leaving them in my 3rd party battery grip caused one of them to drain too much when not in use and start to crack and bulge. I don't know if that's the brand, or a warning to me not to keep batteries in my grip when not in use

Comment: I've added links to the batteries in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the Energizer compatible offers less longevity: 800-970mAh (depends on the exact subtype of the Energizer one) vs. the official 1080mAh of the Canon brand. I could not find any information about the Energizer providing any of the data feedback, such as power level and the like. I did find several sellers that made a key point out about how to go about the first charge, and some caveats with the first charge.

When it comes to Canon batteries, your paying for two things. Obviously, your paying for the Canon name, to a degree. Additionally, you get the Canon guarantee of quality and longevity, full data feedback, and no quirks or restrictions on charging. Having used a few off-brand compatible battery replacements for my XSi myself, I can say one thing with certainty:

Canon batteries last FAR longer than most compatible replacements. On a single fresh charge, my Canon battery would usually last at least two times (2x) longer than any one of my off-brand replacements. When used in extremely cold conditions, the Canon also outperformed the off-brands, although to a lesser degree.

Comment: and don't forget that off-brand batteries will void the warranty on your camera if they leak or otherwise fail. You're paying for that as well.