# Wrong label on battery info section

Tags: canon, digital, camera-settings, battery, camera-basics

I have canon 200D II camera and battery is LP-E17.

When I plugged battery in the camera and checked the battery info section of settings, it shows DR-E18 instead of LP-E17.
And no section of "Maximum Capacity" which shows battery lifespan.

Is it issue in my camera or issue in my battery?

Can I use different battery which isn't produced by Canon?

Comment: Is this a original battery? Because this can happen some time with 3th party part. But I use non-original batteries from more than 6 years w/o any problem.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I got two from seller and the seller mentioned one is original and one is not. But both show the same information. Looks like both are from 3rd party. Glad to hear that you're using the 3rd party battery more than 6 years. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have a Cano 200D/ Rebel SL2? Canon has never made a 200D Mark II.

Comment: Related: [Should I buy an original manufacturer battery, or is a generic brand OK?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1339/15871) and [What's the difference between Canon EOS battery packs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39734/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC 200D II is available in several markets.

Comment: @discover Could you provide a link or at least indicate which marketing areas?

Comment: It seems the EOS 200D Mark II and the EOS 250D/EOS Rebel SL3 are the same camera that uses the LP-E17 battery (or the DR-E18 battery coupler combined with an appropriate transformer such as the AC-E6 AC Adapter).

Comment: https://www.canon.co.nz/cameras/eos-200d-mark-ii
 and      
https://sg.canon/en/consumer/eos-200d-ii-ef-s-18-55mm-f-4-5-6-is-stm/product

@MichaelC

Answer (score 3):

This you observe can happen some time with 3th party parts (can be battery, grip, etc.). From other side some 3th party manufacturers produce very good parts which are by reliability undistinguished from OEM.

I personally bought batteries (almost 4 years ago) for 200D and so far they work fine. Here is the [link](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B06W2LZ3H5/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) of the product (no affiliate with site or manufacturer). Unfortunately this model battery is no longer offered by this brand.

Also I use non-original batteries from more than 6 years w/o any problem (on Canon EOS 5D Mark III). Even they are from different brands.

Comment: Is there any good way to check if battery is from OEM. Because OEM ones are much expensive, I want to confirm that I got the correct one from camera seller.

Comment: Also, an OEM battery will say "Canon" or "Nikon" or whatever the brand of camera is.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use different battery which isn't produced by Canon?

When I bought my Canon Rebel XS at a reputable dealer here in town, the sales guy actually *recommended* a 3rd party battery. He was a career news photographer and said that they *always* bought 3rd party batteries at work. I also have a mix of OEM & 3rd party for my Rebel 4Ti, and have used 1 of each in a 2-battery grip.

All of these have worked with no problems for *years*. I've had the Rebel XS for going on 12 years, and the 4Ti was purchased (used) about 8 years ago. Never had any issues with either OEM or 3rd party batteries.

Answer (score 2):

The DR-E18 is a "dummy" battery that plugs into a transformer connected to wall power (called "mains power" in some countries) and fits into the battery slot in cameras that use the LP-E17 battery.

If your camera thinks the third party battery is a DR-E18 it won't provide recharge information because it thinks the device is powered by a wall outlet.

As to whether you can use third party batteries with your Cano EOS camera: You can. If you want optimal results similar to Canon branded batteries, use third party batteries from reputable brands and buy them from reputable sellers. The latter advice is also true if you choose to use genuine Canon batteries. There are many counterfeit "Canon" batteries in the marketplace. Only buy Canon batteries from authorized Canon dealers or you're probably being sold fakes.

For more about whether to use third party batteries or not, please see:

[Should I buy an original manufacturer battery, or is a generic brand OK?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1339/15871)

I've had very good luck with third party brands such as Maximal Power (only officially available through amazon, though counterfeit Maximal Power batteries seem to now infiltrate amazon via marketplace sellers that submit items comingled with amazon's own inventory), Sterling Tek, Pawa (sold by B&H in the U.S.), and Watson. No quality third party battery seller will try to pass off their products as genuine Canon batteries. They'll put their own brand name on them.

Comment: Hopefully, only my battery is counterfeit and my camera is genuine. :)