# Are third party DSLR batteries significantly less reliable than the official ones?

Tags: canon, battery

The official Canon battery for my camera (LP-E17) costs around $55 while third party batteries sell for about $20. Are Canon's official batteries really worth the price or would I be okay getting an aftermarket product?

Comment: Probably a more generic duplicate that is a closer match to this question: [Should I buy an original manufacturer battery, or is a generic brand OK?
up vote](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1339/15871) or

Comment: For what it's worth, I had a decent 3rd party additional battery for my EOS 6D, and it just doesn't have the power for video recording. After a few seconds of recording, the camera power just cuts out

Comment: @laurencemadill For what it's worth, [Should we encourage / allow comments with helpful advice to questions we know will be closed?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4797/15871)

Comment: @MichaelClark ok thanks, I won't be offended if you delete my comment  if you feel it's not suitable

Answer (score 1):

I have purchased quite a few backup batteries for both Canon and Sony and never had issues, but I think it helps to look for brands that have had enough sales (on Amazon or a similar site with user reviews) to avoid the "bad ones". Definitely do *not* go for the cheapest you can find if there are any hints that it could be a compromise in quality. If the battery leaks or blows up or somehow damages the camera, your cheap battery will end up being quite pricey, so err on the side of caution. The other thing that works well is to charge your camera, inside your bag, when you wouldn't otherwise be able to plug in. You can use an inexpensive external USB battery without voiding your camera warranty and for a fraction of the price. And high-capacity USB batteries can recharge a camera battery several times.