# Where can I buy an original Nikon battery that is certain to be genuine?

Tags: nikon, equipment-recommendation, battery

It is well known how useful it is to have a second battery for your DSLR camera. Besides it is advisable to use original brand equipment, [specially when it comes to batteries](https://www.diyphotography.net/batteries-something-want-buy-original-even-exuberant-pricing/). So, I'm currentley looking for a new and original Nikon battery for my D3300 (the battery is an EN-EL14a 7.2V) but it has been impossible to find one! First I found one in  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FXYTLIK) but some of people commented that the battery wasn't original in spite of the price. So I looked for it on the [Nikon USA](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/batteries/27126/en-el14a-rechargeable-li-ion-battery.html) page, where they recommend some stores (in Miami in my case). In the only one among the ones they recommend where I could find the battery that works for me, was  [Best Buy](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nikon-rechargeable-lithium-ion-battery-for-nikon-en-el14a/3201155.p?skuId=3201155) but as far as I know that's  not a trust worthy place when it comes to warranties (as you can tell by the comments in [here](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.bestbuy.com)).

So what I came to ask you guys today is: Is there any place in which I can buy a original Nikon battery safeley? Have any of you have had troubles like this before?

Thank you all in advance

(Ps: Excuse my grammar and spelling and everything, I'm not English native speaker).

Comment: There are good OEM batteries. I have a Baxxtar battery, one third of the price of the Canon, but twice as expensive as all other brands, and I can' t see the difference with the original Canon one after three years. I also had a Baxxtar battery on my previous camera so that's 9 years total without any problems.

Comment: @Xiota OEM is ambiguous. Let's say "aftermarket".

Comment: @xenoid No, OEM means Original Equipment Manufacturer. Non-OEM is after market.

Comment: This *is* ambiguous. OEM generally *does not* mean that it has a big brand name on it, because Nikon, Canon, et AL don't make batteries themselves. The "OEM" designation original meant "this is made by the actual original manufacturer, same as the branded ones". But it *really* can't be relied on to mean this, *plus* as noted in these comments many people are led to believe that it means big camera-maker name brand.

Comment: Q&A to hopefully [clear up "OEM" terminology confusion](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/109090/1943)

Comment: Btw, this made me check the state of my batteries. The original Canon one is nearly dead according to the battery information in the camera, while the Baxxtar (which I got very soon after getting the camera) is still kicking. Ordering a new pair of Baxxtar ones :)

Comment: @xenoid That could be because the aftermarket batteries are programmed to always report  three green bars regardless of the actual capacity of the battery as it ages, while the Canon batteries actually  measure voltage at full charge and report decreases in full capacity as they age.

Comment: @mattdm It's only ambiguous if you try to force the meaning of a particular term used in the nomenclature of different fields onto the nomenclature used in photographic circles. In a photographic context, *OEM* almost certainly means an item branded and sold via the retail channels of  the company who owns the brand (in this case, Nikon).

Comment: Possible but on the 495 comments on my Amazon nobody mentions incompatibility and one comment says it's compatible. In any case the Baxxtar is at least in as good shape as the Canon (and I made sure I used them in a round-robin fashion, so they have roughly the same cycle count).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I buy an original manufacturer battery, or is a generic brand OK?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/should-i-buy-an-original-manufacturer-battery-or-is-a-generic-brand-ok)

Comment: Hello everybody! Thank you guys for all the coments. I finally decided to follow your advices and buy it on BEst Buy. It was original and new as stated.  Hope this could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand your concern. I personally have bought things on Amazon which looked completely legit but turned out to be fraudulent. (Like, not just generic instead of official, but actually with fake brand silkscreening.)

However, this is generally because Amazon isn't really selling most of the stuff on amazon.com — it's a big network of third-party sellers and it's often hard to tell who is really behind any particular sale. (This is, of course, part of their success.) This means they're a marketplace for all sorts of questionable activity, and Amazon has little real incentive to stop it — they can always point away the blame.

Best Buy isn't like that — they're a singular retail operation. The fact that Nikon links directly to them is indicative of an official relationship that they're unlikely to want to jeopardize. I wouldn't put too much stock in the online complaints site you've linked: there's probably some legitimate problems there but the grab-bag I sampled when skimming is mostly people complaining that their returns weren't accepted out of the store's policy, that they couldn't get large amounts of cash for returns, or that they had to wait too long on hold, etc. None of that particularly indicates fraudulent activity like you might find from [some New York camera stores selling online](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2481355/brooklyn-camera-stores--the-scam-stops-here.html).

There *are* two big NYC camera stores and online retailers which have made some effort to rise above the mess and which I would recommend without hesitation. (No affiliation, just a happy customer.) These are [B & H Photo](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/) and [Adorama](https://www.adorama.com/). Both of these sell both official, branded batteries *and* third-party replacements, but I'm quite confident than they're all labeled correctly and that if you do buy an official Nikon battery, that's what you'll get.

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally decided to buy it on Best Buy. It was the most unexpensive price I could find and it finally turned out to be legit and good. You were right!.

Answer (score 3):

**Warranty service is with Nikon**, not Best Buy or any other retailer. If Nikon says you can buy a genuine product someplace, then you can (and you *did*).

If you're concerned a product is not genuine, **verify the serial number on the manufacturer website**. If you're unable to figure it out, you'll likely have difficulty making a claim because it's usually a required step.

A good principle to keep in mind is, "If it's too good to be true, it is." – That "Nikon" battery listed for $5 is fake.